# How to unprefix configuration section item?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration

To configure my services, **I need to set singleton by instance** like this:

```
        IConfigurationSection settingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        MySettings settings = new MySettings();
        settingsSection.Bind(settings);

        // something to do with the instance, so I need it here

        services.Configure<MySettings>(settings);
```

When I inspect `settingsSection` items, I see its keys are all prefixed with *Appsettings:* (ie: `AppSettings:AppId`, `AppSettings:AppUrl`, ...).

Thus, binding is not done and my `settings` object isn't initialized.

Is there a way to prevent this prefix, as I already know I'm in that section?

Here is how the appsettings.json looks like:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "AppId": 3540350,
    "AppUrl": "http://localhost:542",
    "AppEnabled": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Here is how MySettings class looks like:

```
public class MySettings
{
    public int AppId { get; set;}
    public string AppUrl { get; set;}
    public bool AppEnabled { get; set;}
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

I stupidly kept an old naming convention that can't be deserialized (I guess):

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "App.Id": 3540350,
    "App.Url": "http://localhost:542",
    "App.Enabled": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

That question can be closed.

Comment: There's an extension method that receives the section and configure the `IOptions` so you would only have to do something like `services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"))`

Comment: @dcg "I need to set singleton by instance"

Answer (score 0):

If you want `settings` to be singleton I guess you could use the extension method `Get` of `IConfigurationSection`, something like this:

```cs
var settings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<MySettings>();
services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

Image of sample web project running:

[image]

Comment: Already tried, the section has the right items but instance is not initialized. I guess it's because injection is not done yet.

Comment: Uhmm, I'm sure I've done this before and worked like it was supposed to.

Comment: BTW, `AppId` is an integer but in the configuration is a string.

Comment: @sinsedrix I've just reproduced this in a sample web project and it's working. I scaffolded a view with the details of the `MySettings` instance injected into the `HomeController` and it's displaying the values in the `appsettings.json` file.